# Could Netty be used with DDS

Tags: netty, data-distribution-service

I need to develop application receiving datagram from [OpenDDS](http://opendds.org/) and storing it in a database. [Netty](https://netty.io/) has the excellent performance and stability in Network Application. So i want to use netty framework to receive and store. But i am uncentain about it.
Anyone could give some hint?Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Netty is a framework to build network application and supports UDP / Datagram so yes you can definitely use it for this. You will just need to implement your own encoder / decoder and handler for the business logic.